# how to get return in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager request in afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-2

Hi  i am posting data in using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager class getting the response from server but not able to return data . method  return is executed first then success data is coming i want to get the value in return .

this is my code
**.h file**

```
@interface ServerRequest : NSObject
{

}

-(NSString *) JsonData:(NSString *)newparams actionmethod:(NSString *)action parameters:(NSDictionary *)params;
```

**.m**

```
#import "ServerRequest.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@implementation ServerRequest
{



}

-(NSDictionary *) getJsonData:(NSString *)anynewparams 
                 actionmethod:(NSString *)action 
                   parameters:(NSDictionary *)params {

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString *url = @"http://gjkhdhdyi/ghdgd/Rest/";
    url = [url stringByAppendingString:action];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
    [manager 
    POST:weburl 
    parameters:params
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         json=responseObject;
         // here i am getting data 

    }

    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];

    return json;    
}
```

Now i am calling this method in my ViewController class after importing this i called like this

```
ServerRequest *servercall=[[ServerRequest alloc]init];
returninfo=[servercall getJsonData:nil actionmethod:@"loginuser?" parameters:inputs]
// here i want return data.
```

issue is here not getting return here . but in Method i am getting . so how to get json data after success Request , how to do this

Comment: Read about block and how to use them. What you try to do isn't possible.

Comment: can you tell me where i have to change code

Comment: You need to implement blocks this way you can return the data back to calling function `getJsonData`

Comment: No, read about blocks until you get the answer yourself. If I would give you the working code this wouldn't help you at all because then the rest of your application would not work anymore. You have to learn how to build networking code. Really. There is no shortcut.

Comment: @dasdom Yes we can achieve this through the completion block

Comment: @jace please look at my answer as per you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request method uses blocks, which will won't execute immediately, but instead get dispatched/scheduled, so the method returns before the request can complete (thus the nil value) You could refactor your method to use success/error blocks:

**.h file**

```
-(void)getJsonData:(NSString *)anynewparams 
  actionmethod:(NSString *)action 
    parameters:(NSDictionary *)params 
    onComplete:(void (^)(NSDictionary *json))successBlock 
       onError:(void (^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;
```

**.m file**

```
-(void)getJsonData:(NSString *)anynewparams 
      actionmethod:(NSString *)action 
        parameters:(NSDictionary *)params 
        onComplete:(void (^)(NSDictionary *json))successBlock 
           onError:(void (^)(NSError *error))errorBlock {

    NSString *url = @"http://gjkhdhdyi/ghdgd/Rest/";
    url = [url stringByAppendingString:action];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

    [manager POST:weburl parameters:params
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         successBlock(responseObject);
     }

    failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         errorBlock(error);
     }];
}
```

**Then later:**

```
ServerRequest *servercall=[[ServerRequest alloc] init];
[servercall getJsonData:nil actionmethod:@"loginuser?" parameters:inputs onComplete:^(NSDictionary *json) {

    // return json ehre
} onError:^(NSError *error) {

    // handle error here
}];
```

Comment: i am getting error no interface is visible when i am adding on onComplete

Comment: [servercall getJsonData:nil actionmethod:@"loginuser?" parameters:inputs onComplete:^(NSDictionary *json) {

    // return json ehre
} onError:^(NSError *error) {
 in this line

Comment: Modify also in your header ;)

Comment: how to return json  i am getting data onComplete , ServerRequest *servercall=[[ServerRequest alloc] init];
[servercall getJsonData:nil actionmethod:@"loginuser?" parameters:inputs onComplete:^(NSDictionary *json) {
 NSLog(@"alll ==%@",json);
        
        returninfo = json;
    
} onError:^(NSError *error) {

    // handle error here
}]; out side of block     NSLog(@"this is data==%@",returninfo); is nil , this line executed befor on complete.

Comment: Why don't you just `return json` in the success block?

Comment: @jace do what ever u want to do in success block, the value out side the block will be always nil as per above answer.

Comment: If you declare a variable _outside_ of a block, you can only modify it _inside_ a block if you prepend it with the `__block` modifier.

Comment: [Here](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/blocks) is a good tutorial on Objective-C blocks, it might help you understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this also -

**.h file**

```
- (NSDictionary *) getJsonData:(NSString *)anynewparams actionmethod:(NSString *)action parameters:(NSDictionary *)params onComplete:(void (^)(NSDictionary *json))successBlock
              onError:(void (^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;
```

**.m file**

```
-(NSDictionary *) getJsonData:(NSString *)anynewparams actionmethod: (NSString *)action parameters:(NSDictionary *)params
                onComplete:(void (^)(NSDictionary *json))successBlock
                   onError:(void (^)(NSError *error))errorBlock{
__block id json;

NSString *url = @"http://gjkhdhdyi/ghdgd/Rest/";
url = [url stringByAppendingString:action];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

[manager POST:url parameters:params
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     successBlock(responseObject);
 }
 failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
return json;
}
```

**Call this method in ViewController class**

```
-(void)call_LoginWebService{
 returninfo=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];

BaseRequest *basecall=[[BaseRequest alloc]init];
[basecall getJsonData:nil actionmethod:@"LoginUser?" parameters:inputs onComplete:^(NSDictionary *json) {

    NSLog(@"alll data here  ==%@",json);
    returninfo = json;

} onError:^(NSError *error) {
    // handle error here
}];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Here in the `.m` you create a variable `__block id json`, but never actually assign it. Ih the method call, you assign the value of the response to `resultInfo`, which is not a `__block` variable.

Comment: @JózsefVesza i tried this code and it is working fine for me. you could also try it and let me know

Comment: That's alright, but in `.m` you don't use the return value at all (and you don't even set it), so I would say it could easily be a void. If you actually want to return the result, you could wait until the success block executes with a dispatch group.

Comment: @JózsefVesza return json will always return dictionary results because it is id and in method it is dictionary

Comment: I understand that. Check your method implementation. You create the variable: `__block id json;`, and you return it `return json;`, but you never assign a value to it.

Comment: @Imran dont copy the answer of other users  from  József Vesza

Comment: @jace from where i copied come on man. i m trying to help as per ur question. It is optional way u could try like this also

Comment: what is optional ? there

Comment: @jace man.  check your question first. what u asked and what method u r using in server class and what r u returning. you r not able to get response and i m trying to help that for u.

Comment: @JózsefVesza when we use __block the changes are done inside the block are also outside of it. as jace is trying to call from server class and how the dictionary value will be fetched. if u want to refer about block please refer  this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6